# Search result is always the same independently of query

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, search-results

in a SP Foundation 2013 we are always getting same results independently of search query entered: results always include the same documents (approx. 300 in a total of thousands).

All documents seem to have been correctly crawled.
We are using installation defaults, including result sources.

Where should we begin to look into?

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION**
We created a new result source with this query:

`{?{searchTerms} (IsDocument=True)}`

Comment: Your search query would be incorrect.To veirfy Open the results page -> edit page -> edit "search results" webpart ->in edit properties of webpart select "change query" button -> then in the pop up opened select "Basics" or "Test" to test and verify your query. If everything is fine here then check your result source's query.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your query is executing before receiving your search terms like it happened to [this blogger](http://blog.ithinksharepoint.com/2013/08/20/sharepoint-2013-search-keep-getting-search-results-even-when-there-is-no-query-made/):

According to [this article on technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn186229.aspx#BKMK_How_does_query_transform_affect_query), you could solve the issue by encapsulating your query terms like this:

```
{?{searchTerms}}
```

Comment: Lucas Rodrigues you pointed me in the right direction. I solved by creating a custom Result Source with this query:
`{?{searchTerms} (IsDocument=True)}`